# How and where to deploy my maven project in a cloud server

Tags: spring, git, maven, jenkins, web-deployment

I need to deploy and test my Spring application **tar** in apache server.

For this i know i have to configure a **jenkins** and **apache**.

I will have my code in git hub.

How to configure to build my application into tar and then to deploy in a server automatically?

I need to automate the complete process. How can I do this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: never heard of a "tar" application. Take a look at Openshift.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [Deploy Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Deploy+Plugin). I used it with [apache tomcat](http://tomcat.apache.org/) and it works well.

Answer (score 1):

First, Apache is just HTTP server, it doesn't have the Java Servlet, JavaServer Pages, Java Expression Language and Java WebSocket technologies engines that your Spring web application would need. For that you would need in addition something like Apache's [Tomcat](http://tomcat.apache.org/) or Oracle's [Weblogic](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/middleware/weblogic/overview/index-085209.html).

Let's say you're using Spring Boot, and want to deploy it to a Tomcat 7 instance running in a Ubuntu server/container. You should configure your Spring project to package a **war** file, build it on a Jenkins job and place it in the proper Tomcat's webapps dir (default: /var/lib/tomcat7). There's a good article covering most of that [here](https://spring.io/blog/2014/03/07/deploying-spring-boot-applications).

If you have one of those running instance running in the same server as Jenkins, consider also using Docker for setting up isolated containers for building, testing and deploying. More on that [here](https://spring.io/guides/gs/spring-boot-docker/).